# Turning MouseWheelZoom on and off

Tags: openlayers-3

How do I toggle the Mouse Wheel Zoom functionality?

I know you can set the mousewheelzoom default at map creation:

```
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
        mouseWheelZoom: false
    }),
```

But how do I change it once the map is created i.e. when user clicks the map I want to run a routine which switches mouse wheel zoom back on?

I know this was tricky in Openlayers2 - you had to cycle through the controls:

```
function PMA_Mapping_Enable_Mouse_Wheel_Zoom(map) {
//Need to go through all controls - don't know why!
controls = map.getControlsByClass('OpenLayers.Control.Navigation');
for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; ++i)
    controls[i].enableZoomWheel();};
```

Don't know if that helps but thought I should include it.

Does anyone know how to achieve this in openlayers 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mouseweel is an interaction not a control.
so, you can always use the

`interaction.setActive(true)`, `interaction.setActive(false)` to toggle the interaction.

Start your map initialazation like so:

`......interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
        mouseWheelZoom: false
    }), .......`

Then once your map is ready create the mouseWheel interaction like so:

`var mouseWheelInt = new ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom();
 map.addInteraction(mouseWheelInt)`

and then toggle it :

`mouseWheelInt.setActive(!mouseWheelInt.getActive())`

Comment: That's much better - no need to store a client side toggle variable now either! Transitioning from OL2 takes some getting used to - this helps a lot. Many thanks.

Comment: glad to help mate!